# python read(4) returning a string of length 1 not 4

Tags: python, io, floating-point, binaryfiles

I have a large binary file of ieee 32bit floating point numbers.

In python I use:

```
f = file.read(4)
    while f !='':
        if len(f) == 4:
            data =struct.unpack('>f', f)
            print data
f = file.read(4)
```

to read it 4 bytes at a time

However, occasionally f would be size 1, and struct.unpack would complain that its input must be a string of size 4.

The filesize is divisible by 4, and this happens multiple times within the file.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you open the file in binary mode?

Anyway, a much better way to read your file is to use [`array.fromfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#array.array.fromfile) or NumPy.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, i recommend against the use of the word `file` as a variable, as it is a `__builtin__` function.

Secondly, binary mode or ascii mode?

Comment: Bah >< forgot that windows treats text and binary files differently.

Comment: You could also just treat all files as binary files, which is technically true, ;p

Answer (score 3):

See this page: [file.read](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.read)

Specifically

> Also note that when in non-blocking mode, less data than was requested may be returned, even if no size parameter was given.

Comment: It's very unlikely the OP opened the file in non-blocking mode. On Windows, that's not even possible.